# Updating values in an external file only works if I restart the shell window

Tags: python-3.x

Hi there and thank you in advance for your response! I'm very new to python so please keep that in mind as you read through this, thanks!

So I've been working on some code for a very basic game using python (just for practice) I've written out a function that opens another file, selects a variable from it and adjusts that variable by an amount or if it's a string changes it into another string, the funtion looks like this.

```
def ovr(file, target, change):
with open(file, "r+") as open_file:
    opened = open_file.readlines()
    open_file.close()

with open(file, "w+") as open_file:
    position = []
    for appended_list, element in enumerate(opened):
        if target in element:
            position.append(appended_list)

    if type(change) == int:
        opened[position[0]] = (str(target)) + (" = ") + (str(change)) + (str("\n"))
        open_file.writelines(opened)
        open_file.close()
            
    else:
        opened[position[0]] = (str(target)) + (" = ") + ("'") + (str(change)) + ("'") + (str("\n"))
        open_file.writelines(opened)
        open_file.close()

for loop in range(5):
ovr(file = "test.py", target = "gold", change = gold + 1)
```

At the end I have basic loop that should re-write my file 5 times, each time increasing the amount of gold by 1. If I write this ovr() funtion outside of the loop and just run the program over and over it works just fine increasing the number in the external file by 1 each time.

Edit: I should mention that as it stands if I run this loop the value of gold increases by 1. if I close the shell and rerun the loop it increases by 1 again becoming 2. If I change the loop to happen any number of times it only ever increases the value of gold by 1.

Edit 2: I found a truly horrific way of fixing this isssue, if anyone has a better way for the love of god please let me know, code below.

```
for loop in range(3):
    ovr(file = "test.py", target = "gold", change = test.gold + 1)
    reload(test)
    sleep(1)
    print(test.gold)
```

The sleep part is because it takes longer to rewrite the file then it does to run the full loop.

Answer (score 0):

you can go for a workaround and write your new inforamtion into a file called: file1

So you can use ur working loop outside of the write file. Anfter using your Loop you can just change the content of your file by the following steps.
This is how you dont need to rewrite your loop and still can change your file content.
first step:

```
with open('file.text', 'r') as input_file, open('file1.txt', 'w') as output_file:

for line in input_file:
    output_file.write(line)
```

second step:

```
with open('file1.tex', 'r') as input_file, open('file.tex', 'w') as output_file:
    for line in input_file:
        if line.strip() == '(text'+(string of old value of variable)+'text)':
            output_file.write('text'+(string of new value of variable)+' ')
        else:
            output_file.write(line)
```

then you have updated your text file.

Comment: as Iam a Beginner in Python there might be a lot of better Ways to do this, but this i a workaround which might help you till someone else posts a better one

Comment: I do actually like this solution, I did play around with something similar myself and I may  have to go with this. I would prefer a more elegant solution though, and really I would like to understand why this doesen't work as it is and why restarting the shell makes it work. Thanks for the post though, genuinely is very helpful.